# Android WebSite, file upload timeout

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net, html, web

**Use-case**

1. SmartPhone Website
2. is used to upload files to the server

**Problem**

- While using Android (Galaxy III) uploading large files over the ocean ( low throughput ) the upload http request is timing out, terminated by the Android device.
- doing the same using a Windows PC works fine

Is there any settings on the Android device to extend the upload request timeout ?
How can this be resolved ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java

Comment: I need a JavaScript solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488764/settimeout-not-called-in-android-webkit

Comment: I need to be able to setup the form submission timeout, seems as if the submission request is timed out preventing me to upload files from my Android device