# Video DOM function in mobile browser : how to stop video from a timed function

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I was trying to control mobile html video from a timeout function, but I found strange behavior.
When I try to stop playing video by clicking a button, it works.
But when I try to stop it from a timed function, it doesn't work.
How do I make it work?

```js
function doStop(){
    var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
    myvideo.pause();
}
```

```html
<input type=button value='stopit' onclick='doStop()' > <!-- it works -->
<input type=button value='stopit' onclick='setTimeout("doStop()", 3000)'> <!- This doesn't -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="myvideo" width="400" controls>
     <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>



<input type=button value='stopit' onclick='doStop()' > <!-- it works -->
<input type=button value='stopit' onclick='setTimeout(doStop, 2000)'>

</body> 
<script>
var doStop=  function() {
    var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
    myvideo.pause();
}
</script>
</html>
```

try this `onclick='setTimeout(doStop, 3000)'`

Comment: Hmm. I thought it worked, but it is executed as soon as I click the button;
the function is not timed.

Comment: I changed the function as follows. doStop function is called. But only the video control is not working.

function doStop(){
    var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
    myvideo.pause();  // this has no effect
    alert("Hi");   // This is executed.
}

once again, when directly called, alert and pause both works.

Comment: @SehyeongCho try running the code snippet in the answer. The video is short so click stop as soon as you play the video.

Comment: In Windows, no problem.
In Android, I got a problem.

Comment: @SehyeongCho there are lot of issues reported with setTimeout in Android webview, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488764/settimeout-not-called-in-android-webkit) try this approach. Extract your function to a variable and use it in the setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks. 
setTimeout works fine. The doStop function is called no problem in either case. The weird thing is, of the sentences in the doStop function, only the sentence that tries to pause video has no effect.
Maybe a privilege issue???
I'll take a look at the link you suggested.
Thank you once again.